# After Upgrading Xcode Version 14.0 I Start to get espresso message in the console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I upgraded Xcode to 14.0 and my test device iOS to 16.0 then I start to get message below in console for one of my SwiftUI project.

It looks like following code making it. Every time this part called we are getting the message.

```
  let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: cmBuffer, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: 6)!, options: requestOptions)
    
   
    
    do {
        
        try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
    
    } catch {
        
        print(error)
        
    }
```

**[1235:196713] [espresso] [Espresso::handle_ex_plan] exception=Inconsistent phase of espresso_plan: 0 status=-5** message in console.

I could not find why I am getting and how to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you just using wrong value for `recognitionLevel` parameter. Make sure it's `.fast` for real time handling.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same message, and on similar code too. Xcode 14, iOS 16. Looks like some things got `inconsistent`

Comment: Do you also get **should be called from background thread** for startRunning AVCaptureSession. I am using SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `recognitionLevel` on the `VNRecognizeTextRequest` to `.fast`:

```
func performTextRecognition(_ cgImage: CGImage) {
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage)
          
        // Create a new request to recognize text.
          let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: self.recognizeTextHandler)
          request.recognitionLevel = .fast

        do {
          // Perform the text-recognition request.
          try requestHandler.perform([request])
        } catch {
          print("Unable to perform the requests: \(error).")
        }
    }
```